# Is Eastern orthodox christian is also called Jacobite?

Tags: eastern-orthodox

Is there any relation between Eastern Orthodox Christian and Jacobites? Are they both different?

Comment: "Jacobite" refers to [many different things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobite), some of which are connected to Eastern Christianity. You'll have to be more specific for this question to reopen open however.

Comment: I am assume by "Jacobite" you MIGHT mean the Syriac Orthodox Church, as opposed to the 17th century political movement in the UK. Please confirm, and I am sure you will get many well-informed answers.

Comment: See [Malankara Jacobite Syrian Orthodox Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malankara_Jacobite_Syrian_Orthodox_Church) on Wikipedia.